# Is there a simple way in VS SSIS to swap existing DB connection manager with existing project connection manager?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT).

I have several packages (about 50) I need to migrate to use the project deployment model (instead of package deployment).

I created a new Project and added my first SSIS package. I converted the existing database connection manager to Project connection and everything worked fine.

I then added my next package to the project. I can see 2 connection managers in the package. 1 being the existing Package connection and the other being the Project connection manager I just created.

Since both connection managers point to the same database, is there a way I can just swap the existing package connection manager with my new Project connection manager so that I won't have to go into all the different tasks in the SSIS package and update them to use the Project Connection manager as this would be very time consuming and prone to error?

I did some research and the best I could find was an article on updating the SSIS packages in a text editor by doing a find and replace. I'm hoping there is an easier more automated way of making the change within Visual Studio? Anyone have any suggestions?

In case it helps anyone:

[Here's an article I found describing how to get around the issue by editing the SSIS XML](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/migration-of-ssis-2008-package-connections-to-ssis-2012-project-connections)

I would have thought this could be done natively within VS without having to edit the package XML.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is no but I can say that I followed the steps in the article and it worked for me using SSDT 2017. Wasn't too bad doing the necessary find and replace in Notedpad ++ (vs the carpal tunnel method of clicking around a million times in VS which is more error prone compared to find and replace)